# PHP Trim special characters , - | from left and right automatically

Tags: php

Is there a way to easily trim out specific extra characters from left and right of a php string along with extra spaces and break lines e.g.

```
$str = " ,apple,orrange,banana, ";
```

to

```
apple,orrange,banana
```

Similarly

```
$str = "|apple|orrange|banana||";
```

to

```
apple|orrange|banana
```

Comment: Ooops, meant to say apple|orrange|banana as I just need extra characters removed form left and right side if the same character is in the middle of the string it shoud not be changed

Comment: What prevented you from simply reading the `trim` documentation?

Comment: or something like that: `preg_replace('#^[^a-z]*+((?:(?![^a-z]*+$).)*+)[^a-z]*+$#i', '$1', $str)`

Comment: A simple google search would have given you everything you need. -1

Comment: Sorry a newbie here :(

Comment: All good, just make sure you re/search your question before you come here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP `trim()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) has second parameter **Character Mask** which can be used in your case.

```
$fieldValue = ",|banana,orange,Yahooo||| ";
$v = trim($fieldValue," \t\n\r\0\x0B,-|");
echo $v;
```

The output will be

```
banana,orange,Yahooo
```